# How to connect TCP/IP device with Azure IoT hub and also the device is non programmable

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-central

I want to connect a device that is working on TCP/IP protocol with the Azure IoT hub the thing which can be modified in the device is the IP address and port number I went through the azure IoT hub documentation and came to know it supports the following communication protocol:

1. MQTT
2. MQTT over WebSockets
3. AMQP
4. AMQP over WebSockets
5. HTTPS

This is the link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-protocols)

so my question is how can I connect this type of device with the Azure IoT hub

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate issue of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/462121/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To connect a HTTP client device with IoT Hub, you can use de SDK if your microcontroller have enouth capacity to run:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-iot-hub?pivots=programming-language-ansi-c

Another way is use de REST API from IoT Hub:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/rest/api/iothub/

Comment: thanks for the answer but the device does not support HTTP protocol it only supports TCP/IP protocol so I am only allowed to change the IP address and Port number

Comment: In this way, you can use TCP or UDP protocol to send packages to a middleware software component, like a service in a container running on Azure Container Instance, and this middleware translate the packates to HTTP or MQTT to IoT Hub using Azure IoT SDK.